# Backgound Image in div class

Tags: html, css

I want put background image with external CSS but image doesn't show.

where I do wrong here ? Please suggest

```css
   .Header {
      background-image: url(<Images\HeaderBackground.jpeg>);
      height: auto;
      width: 100%
    }
```

```html
   <div class="Header">
        <img class="Logo" src=images/logo2.jpg alt="Company Logo" width="110" height="35">
        <center>
          <span>
            <h1 class="Company">IT Solution</h1>
          </span>
        </center>
      </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use this: `background-image: url('Images\HeaderBackground.jpeg');`

Comment: @MinalChauhan wrong "\", you should use "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change how you path the url:

```
.Header {
background-image: url('Images/HeaderBackground.jpeg');
height: auto;
width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answer correcting your syntax, which was already mentioned by other users to:

`background-image: url('Images/HeaderBackground.jpeg');`

you should check, if your path to the background image is correct at all.